# Построение TreeView в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста что здесь не так:
Это работает:

```
        @helper BuildMenu(IEnumerable<DepartamentsStructViewModel> data, Decimal? parentId = null)
        {
            var items = data.Where(d => d.DPS_DATESTART < DateTime.Now && d.DPS_DATEFINISH > DateTime.Now && d.DPS_PARID == parentId).OrderBy(i => i.DPS_PREVID);
            if (items.Any())
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <button class="accordion">@item.DPS_NAME</button>
                            @BuildMenu(data, item.DPS_ID)
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        }
```

А это нет:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DepartamentsStruct(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<DepartamentsStructViewModel> data, Decimal? parentId = null)
    {
        var items = data.Where(d => d.DPS_DATESTART < DateTime.Now && d.DPS_DATEFINISH > DateTime.Now && d.DPS_PARID == parentId).OrderBy(i => i.DPS_PREVID);
        TagBuilder ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
        if (items.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                TagBuilder li = new TagBuilder("li"); 
                TagBuilder button = new TagBuilder("button");
                button.AddCssClass("accordion");
                button.SetInnerText(item.DPS_NAME);
                DepartamentsStruct(html, data, item.DPS_ID);
                li.InnerHtml = button.ToString();
                ul.InnerHtml += li.ToString();
            }
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(ul.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Может проблема в том, что вызов `DepartamentsStruct(html, data, item.DPS_ID);` внутри `foreach` по сути ни на что не влияет? Вам надо результат этого вызова добавить к `li` элементу, как я понял, сразу за кнопкой.

Comment: Мне ж в DepartamentsStruct нужно передаватьi tem.DPS_ID без цикла не обойтись

Comment: Я не предлагал цикл убирать. Я предложил в цикле результат рекурсивного вызова как то использовать, так как сейчас он вхолостую работает.

Comment: вот так может li.InnerHtml += DepartamentsStruct(html, data, item.DPS_ID);

Comment: я не знаю, что вы за типы данных используете, потому не знаю, как корректно ваш код поправить, я только указал на проблему в алгоритме. Но идея верная, добавить к li резульат вызова - если скомпилируется, то попробуйте

Comment: Да, это помогло) Спасибо)

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вызов `DepartamentsStruct(html, data, item.DPS_ID);` внутри `foreach` по сути ни на что не влияет. Вам надо результат этого вызова добавить к li элементу, сразу за кнопкой.

```
li.InnerHtml += DepartamentsStruct(html, data, item.DPS_ID);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @Yaroslav пожалуйста. Рад, что помог. Отметье ответ плиз галочкой